# Recommendation for Free PHP basic auction script

Tags: php

I need the most simple auction script you can imagine.
I dont need categories, just a listing of items in a single page.

It needs to have a description with pictures.
I have mysql, php, cgi, perl, ruby .. and a lot of other stuff installed on my server, but I prefer PHP.
Can anyone please give me an idea of such a basic script ? Free/GPL is preferred of course :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Auction Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636077/php-auction-script)

Comment: Also, [googling yields quite a number of results](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+auction+scripts). Have you tried any of these yet and can rule out any?

Comment: I took a look at that link.. AJ Aution is too powerful and I need something simple. On the other page 2 links dont work, 1 is in german and the other one looks like a PHP copy of AJ Auction..

Comment: thanks for clarifying why the linked SO question did not meet your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the identical question and shortly after finding this post, I stumbled across WeBid: http://www.webidsupport.com -- Also curious how you'll be handling the payment gateway.

Comment: I also tried using WeBid. It's too complex for my needs though. What I did is I wrote the auction myself. I didn't have to cope with payment gateway trouble since after the auction is done, my company simply gets in touch with the people and meets the two sides of the auction.

Comment: +1 Since I was going to create my own from scratch, this is the best thing as a skeleton!  thank you for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at scripting repositories:

http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/auctions/

Bearing in mind the nature of auction services, and the need for secure transaction placing/processing, any script that has this in place to a reasonably safe degree is more than likely priced, and will have a far more enriched featureset that the one you are looking for.

If you are looking to create a public auction portal, I would recommend a paid for service/platform and/or leveraging off the toolsets from major vendors like ebay. If it is for your own personal use, you can create something pretty easily using PHP/mySQL/(JS) and then plug it into paypal or similar for payment processing. That said, again, because you are dealing in monetary exchange- I would strongly recommend a professional solution.

Comment: I have an already working website, it has SSL encryption and is being monitored 24/7, transactions dont even have to be online - we will manually call both parties and help them get in touch. This is why I said it should be SIMPLE. I know I can write it in a few hours but I was wondering if I could save some time. I'll check out the link you've provided.